# validating textbox checking if it isn't readonly first

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have a form with two modes 
one that allows edit (value of text box)

and another mode for (non-manager) user - code behind adding "READONLY" to the TextBox tag.

so with the readonly 'mode' there's no input accepted in text box at all

my question is how could i execute validation method based on "READONLY" property of text box ?

strRo = "READONLY" on a condition

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumbers" runat="server" <%=strRo %> onkeypress="return allowonlynumbers();" />
```

javascript function

```
   function allowonlynumbers() {
        if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
            return true;
            }

        else {
            alert('Only numbers can be entered');
             return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass a reference to the element in your function call, so change the `onkeypress` to this:

```
onkeypress="return allowonlynumbers(this);"
```

Then, your function needs to be like this:

```
function allowonlynumbers(obj) {

}
```

And the logic you can use is:

```
if (obj.readOnly) {
    // The element is readonly
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your Answer , didn't have the time to check on it and implement till just now , although by now i had a similar answer by jbabey , you were the first to answer so i owe it to you ! , thanks a lot for all replys !

Answer (score 2):

You should bind your event handler in javascript ([why?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). Then you will be able to use the `this` operator inside of the handler to refer to the textbox, which you can check the `readOnly` property of:

```
document.getElementById('test').onkeypress = function () {
    if (!this.readOnly) {
        if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Only numbers can be entered');
            return false;
        }
    }
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FedsQ/

Comment: thakns for your kind and well informing answer , you have described the whole idea even further than 1'st answer , though i had to mark first as the correct one, sorry about that , yours is the correct one as well !!

Comment: once again i would like to express my appreciation this time on the later link "JSFIDDLE" it's a very nice one ! thanks for that too !!